# Udev, libpam-systemd, systemd-sysv and systemd dependencies errors causes apt to be unusable

Tags: systemd, apt, udev, dependencies, pop-os

After mistakenly downloading pop-desktop again, udev and systemd have dependency errors that make me unable to use apt. When I run sudo apt upgrade, this error shows up:

```
user@computer:~$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpam-systemd : Depends: systemd (= 249.11-0ubuntu3.1)
 systemd-sysv : Depends: systemd (= 249.11-0ubuntu3.1)
 udev : Breaks: systemd (< 249.11-0ubuntu3.1)
        Breaks: systemd:i386 (< 249.11-0ubuntu3.1)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

When I try sudo apt --fix-broken install:

```
user@computer:~$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libpam-systemd libudev1 libudev1:i386 systemd-sysv udev
The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:
  libpam-systemd libudev1 libudev1:i386 systemd-sysv udev
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 5 downgraded, 0 to remove and 63 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/2,708 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of systemd:
 udev (249.11-0ubuntu3.1) breaks systemd (<< 249.11-0ubuntu3.1) and is installed.
  Version of systemd to be configured is 249.11-0ubuntu3pop0~1650312774~22.04~cecf6af.

dpkg: error processing package systemd (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a 
previous failure.
                 Errors were encountered while processing:
 systemd
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

After doing that command, I went to multiple sources and could not find a solution to fix my situation.

I tried sudo dpkg --configure -a and it came back with this:

```
 user@computer:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of systemd:
 udev (249.11-0ubuntu3.1) breaks systemd (<< 249.11-0ubuntu3.1) and is installed.
  Version of systemd to be configured is 249.11-0ubuntu3pop0~1650312774~22.04~cecf6af.

dpkg: error processing package systemd (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of systemd-timesyncd:
 systemd-timesyncd depends on systemd (= 249.11-0ubuntu3pop0~1650312774~22.04~cecf6af); however:
  Package systemd is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package systemd-timesyncd (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libnss-systemd:amd64:
 libnss-systemd:amd64 depends on systemd (= 249.11-0ubuntu3pop0~1650312774~22.04~cecf6af); however:
  Package systemd is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libnss-systemd:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 systemd
 systemd-timesyncd
 libnss-systemd:amd64
```

I tried sudo apt -f install and sudo apt --fix-broken install :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libpam-systemd libudev1 libudev1:i386 systemd-sysv udev
The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:
  libpam-systemd libudev1 libudev1:i386 systemd-sysv udev
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 5 downgraded, 0 to remove and 63 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/2,708 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of systemd:
 udev (249.11-0ubuntu3.1) breaks systemd (<< 249.11-0ubuntu3.1) and is installed.
  Version of systemd to be configured is 249.11-0ubuntu3pop0~1650312774~22.04~cecf6af.

dpkg: error processing package systemd (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a 
previous failure.
                 Errors were encountered while processing:
 systemd
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I also tried Synaptic:

```
                         Errors were encountered while processing:
 systemd
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
A package failed to install.  Trying to recover:
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of systemd:
 udev (249.11-0ubuntu3.1) breaks systemd (<< 249.11-0ubuntu3.1) and is installed.
  Version of systemd to be configured is 249.11-0ubuntu3pop0~1650312774~22.04~cecf6af.

dpkg: error processing package systemd (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of systemd-timesyncd:
 systemd-timesyncd depends on systemd (= 249.11-0ubuntu3pop0~1650312774~22.04~cecf6af); however:
  Package systemd is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package systemd-timesyncd (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libnss-systemd:amd64:
 libnss-systemd:amd64 depends on systemd (= 249.11-0ubuntu3pop0~1650312774~22.04~cecf6af); however:
  Package systemd is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libnss-systemd:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 systemd
 systemd-timesyncd
 libnss-systemd:amd64
```

Is there any way to fix this udev and systems problem? If this problem has been solved, can you send the link where it has been resolved? Just to let you know, I am using Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS.

Comment: It says this:


```udev:
  Installed: 249.11-0ubuntu3.1
  Candidate: 249.11-0ubuntu3pop0~1650312774~22.04~cecf6af
  Version table:
 *** 249.11-0ubuntu3.1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     249.11-0ubuntu3pop0~1650312774~22.04~cecf6af 1001
       1001 http://apt.pop-os.org/release jammy/main amd64 Packages
     249.11-0ubuntu3 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this same issue on Pop_Os! 22.04 LTS and the answer here https://askubuntu.com/questions/146150/unable-to-fix-broken-packages-with-sudo-apt-get-install-f

fixed the issue for me. I removed the udev entry from that file, ran an apt upgrade which completed successfully.

I then confirmed udev was back in the file and everything seems ok so far and updating via terminal or the pop shop works now, though I am not 100% sure if this will have any negative followup issues.

Be sure to make a backup of the file before you do anything just in case!

Comment: Which answer did you follow in the link?

Comment: This part:

`sudo -i gedit /var/lib/dpkg/status`

(you can use vi or nano instead of gedit)

Locate the corrupt package, and remove the whole block of information about it and save the file.

Comment: How do you backup an entry? Sorry, I'm kind of new to this .

Comment: No problem, we all have to learn :) 

To backup this file, do a copy (cp) in your terminal:

`sudo cp /var/lib/dpkg/status /var/lib/dpkg/status.backup`

I've added some more details to the steps here:

`sudo -i gedit /var/lib/dpkg/status`

(you can use vi or nano instead of gedit)

Locate the corrupt package (in this case it should be _udev_), and remove the whole block of information about it. You can find this by searching for _Package: udev_ in the file.)
Then save the file and run your updates. Good luck!

Comment: Oh no. 
After deleting udev in /var/lib/dpkg/status, all these other packages depended on it!

Comment: `

 alsa-base : Depends: udev
 bluez : Depends: udev
 gnome-bluetooth : Depends: udev (>= 154)
 initramfs-tools-core : Depends: udev
 libpam-systemd : Depends: systemd (= 249.11-0ubuntu3.1)
 libsane1 : Depends: udev
 libsane1:i386 : Depends: udev:i386
                 Recommends: sane-airscan:i386 but it is not installable
 libu2f-udev : Depends: udev (>= 244)
 mdadm : Depends: udev
 network-manager : Depends: udev
 plymouth : Depends: udev (>= 232-8~)
 snapd : Depends: udev
 systemd-sysv : Depends: systemd (= 249.11-0ubuntu3.1)
 tpm-udev : Depends: udev

`

Comment: `
ubuntu-drivers-common : Depends: udev (>= 204-0ubuntu4~)
 ubuntu-minimal : Depends: udev
 udisks2 : Depends: udev
 upower : Depends: udev
 xserver-xorg-core : Depends: udev (>= 149)
`

Comment: Strange, removing it (and only it) worked for me with what I thought was the same root issue you had :(
Did you run `sudo apt update` first?
If you have the backup then you can just look in there for the udev entry and add it back to the original file, or just rename the backup to have its original name, after you change the name of the updated file to something else, like status.fail/status.new etc, then that file is safe to remove.

Comment: It worked! I realized that deleting udev allowed me to use `sudo dpkg configure -a`, and after configuring, I used `sudo apt --fix-broken install`, which fixed it!